# Successfully fetched firestore data does not render (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I created a leaderboard component within React, that displays a list of various individual's names and scores.
I successfully retrieve the data from the Firestore and it prints to my console, but it never ends up rendering to the screen.

I believe this has to be something within the Effect hook but I'm not sure what's wrong with it when I look at other answers. It could also be somehow my leaderboardData variable is never getting populated.

Code to fetch data:

```
const fetchLeaderboardData = async() => {
db.collection('Leaderboard').get()
  .then(snap => {
    snap.docs.map(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data())
      return {
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
        ref: doc.ref
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Effect hook:

```
const [leaderboardData, setLeaderboardData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
(async () => {
  const newLeaderboardData = await fetchLeaderboardData();
  setLeaderboardData(newLeaderboardData);
})();
}, [])
```

Code to render:

```
return (
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="lboard_section">
    <div className="lboard_tabs">
      <div className="tabs">
        <ul>
          <li>All Time</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="lboard_wrap">
    {leaderboardData && leaderboardData.map(item => {
      <div key={item.id} className="lboard_mem">
        <div className="namebar">
          <p>{ item.name }</p>
        </div>
        <div className="points">
          { item.score + " "} points
        </div>
      </div>
    })}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
```

Comment: You should be returning your map: `return snap.docs.map(...` also in general be careful mixing `async/await` stuff and `.then/.catch` stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're. missing two `return` statements in your `fetchLeaderboardData` function.

```
const fetchLeaderboardData = async() => {
  return db.collection('Leaderboard').get().then(snap => {
    return snap.docs.map(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data())
      return {
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
        ref: doc.ref
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Without those return statements, there is no return value from `fetchLeaderboardData`, so the `await fetchLeaderboardData()` doesn't return anything.